# Need help verifying my newly created Apple ID

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id, ipod, itunes-store, apple-store

I want to create an Apple-ID to download viber on my iPod.

Having selected "None" for the payment method and having inserted my address, it takes me out of there.

So, I don't get an email to verify the Apple-ID.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it’s usually Apple’s servers causing the delay. Sometimes it can take a few hours to receive, and/or requires multiple resend requests. The quickest way to resolve the issue is by [Contacting Apple ID support](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/contact/) directly.

That said, they do have a support article for your issue: [**If you didn't receive  your Apple ID verification or reset email**](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201455]).

**To summarize the basics:**

> 1. Check all your mail folders, including spam and junk. The sender address is **appleid@id.apple.com.**
> 2. Confirm that you entered your email address correctly in your [Apple ID account](http://appleid.apple.com)
> 3. Check that your email client is working properly.
> 4. Sign into your account at [My Apple ID](http://appleid.apple.com) and resend the verification email.

Comment: I will try again. Is downloading from the app-store the only method to download viber free to my iPod?